# how to space between images in carousel slider 360

Tags: carousel, joomla3.0

how to space between images in carousel slider 360 
joomla module : [Carousel ck 
demo & download](http://www.joomlack.fr/en/joomla-extensions/carousel-ck) files.

I want insert space between image.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use css. Should work with div element

something like this

```
div.carouselck_images{
  margin: 10px;
}
```